# EC2 - cannot deploy as "bitnami" user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, capistrano, bitnami

I am using Capistrano for deploying a Rails app to Amazon EC2.
In the deploy files, I have following credentials for connecting to Amazon EC2:

```
set :user, "bitnami"
#set :user, "root"
server "ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
ssh_options[:keys] = ["/Users/ada/my_amazon_ec2.pem"]
```

When I run `cap deploy:setup` and `cap deploy:check`, I get following:

```
The following dependencies failed. Please check them and try again:
--> You do not have permissions to write to `/www/myapp'. (ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com)
--> You do not have permissions to write to `/www/myapp/releases'. (ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com)
```

How's that possible? I am able to connect via SSH to EC2 as the user **bitnami**, but when I try it as the user **root**, I get the message that I should use the **bitnami** user for login and the connection is closed.

If I try to change in the deploy files change the **bitnami** user for **root**, the whole deployment process is ok, but then when I log in through SSH (as the **bitnami** user) to EC2, I don't see any files that should be deployed, the final directory is just empty.

What is wrong in this case?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -R <user> <folder path>
```

did the trick. The user was not the owner of the folder and hence cap check was throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the /www/myapp directory already created and does bitnami user have writing permissions there?

Let's assume your application is called "myapp123" and you want to deploy it to /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp123.

Create application directory and set proper permissions:

```
mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp123
chown -R bitnami /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp123
```

Add the following options to your deployment config file:

```
set :application, "myapp123"
set :deploy_to, "/opt/bitnami/apps/#{application}"
```

Are you going to use Phussion Passenger? In this case you will also need to add the following to the Capistrano config:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Which BitNami AMI do you use?

Comment: Hello, the first problem is when I try to create the directory: `mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/bitnami/apps/SherlockDocs': Permission denied` How can I setup the permissions to the user `bitnami`?

Comment: regarding to Phussion Passenger - not at the moment, but I am definitely open to use it, I just need to deploy the app to EC :) I spent last day and a half trying to do this... frustrating.

Comment: Use sudo to execute commands with root permissions:

sudo mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/apps/SherlockDocs ;
sudo chown -R bitnami /opt/bitnami/apps/SherlockDocs

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami stacks usually have default webroot at

`/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs`

Try writing to that folder instead (using bitnami user).

If you would like to change the webroot to another directory, you will need to create the directory and set the proper permissions, as well as tell apache you've changed the web root ([click for more on how to do that](http://drndivoje.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/easy-change-apache-root-web-folder-www/)).

If you are having trouble creating the directory, or applying permissions, prefix your commands with `sudo` like `sudo mkdir www`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Well, finally I can create there the directory, but when I deploy the app, I don't see any errors in the terminal window, but the command `ls` showing still only the empty directory, where the app was deployed... There are not the deployed files. What can be still wrong?

Comment: One more thing - if I will open in the browser the URL with my app (`amazon_url.com/my_app`), I get just the **Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /my_app/ on this server.** page. Here are the permissions of the **my_app** directory: `drwxrwxr-x  2 bitnami bitnami`

Comment: You will need to start the rails server first and if you are deploying in development mode you will need to append `:3000` after the `.com` so  `myurl.com:3000`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this:

```
ssh_options[:auth_methods] = ["publickey"]
```